# Script to copy files, rename it and share it to azure blob

Tags: linux, bash, azure, shell, azure-blob-storage

There is a folder in which the application generates different files, such as those below.

Delhi_20221234556.csv
Melbourne_20123456789.csv
Goa_1234567890.csv
Sydney_2022345689.csv

The script should removes numbers from files as below, then copies them to Azure blob storage, and after copying them to Azure blob, it should move the file to the archive folder with the date.

Delhi.csv
Melbourne.csv
Goa.csv
Sydney.csv

Initially I was doing it for Goa_1234567890.csv as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /abc/def -type f -name 'Goa*' -execdir bash -c 'for f in "$@"; 
do mv "$f" "${f%%_*}.csv"; 
done' bash {} +
./azcopy cp "/abc/def/Goa.csv" "https://<Blobaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/abc\home\xyz?<SAS- Token>"
mv /abc/def/Goa.csv /abc/def/Archive/Goa$(date +%F).csv`
```

Would anyone be able to help me improve the above script to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to generalize your script to handle multiple filenames
other than `Goa*`. Assuming the csv files are located just under the
`/abc/def` directory (not in the subdirectories), would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/abc/def"
mkdir -p "$dir"/Archive/

for f in "$dir/"*.csv; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
        new="${f%%_*}.csv"
        mv -- "$f" "$new"
        ./azcopy cp "$new" "https://<Blobaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/abc\home\xyz?<SAS- Token>"
        base="${new##*/}"
        mv -- "$new" "$dir/Archive/${base%.csv}$(date +%F).csv"
    fi
done
```

Please note it doesn't consider the case there are multiple
filenames which share the same city name with different numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. If you feel my answer
solves well your problem, I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by
clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.